# ASP NET Code First Existing database - no reverse engineering

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I created a new database by Code First and enabled migrations in order to update the database, but the database came under some modifications
and I would like to update my models using the Reverse Engineering approach.

I have searched online and I should right click on the project and from Entity Framework dropdown item, to select the Reverse Engineering option. The only issue is that when I right click on the 
project, there is no Entity Framework item.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Did you install this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d ?

Comment: Still don't much understand code first, nice to have all your code in one place including database especially under source control. But other than that seems rather like a cute toy compared to Entity Framework model first. All kinds of handy things that you can do in seconds with Sql Server Management Studio, take learning new syntax and funky workarounds. Even updating database via migrations is fragile and at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install `Entity Framework Power Tools` extension. There is a list of new features of this tool set:

[Summary of Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx)

As there is mentioned: **Reverse Engineer Code First** - Generates derived DbContext class, POCO classes, and Code First mapping classes for an existing database.